# React Native Expo Deep Linking - Deep-linking not working after the app on production

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking

I created my app with react-native expo and added deep-linking and I tested the deep-linking on develop and on simulator and it is working fine.

Here is working on development =>

```
npx uri-scheme open exp://192.168.1.101:19000/--/ProductScreen?id=95bcc346-9da6-4eff-a45e-6012e83df27b --android
```

Here is working when i get apk and open in simulator =>

```
npx uri-scheme open myapp://ProductScreen?id=95bcc346-9da6-4eff-a45e-6012e83df27b --android
```

But how can i open this through a link. Because i should share that link with anyone and i want that person to open my app with that openable link.

```
    const handleShare = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await Share.share({
                url: `exp://192.168.1.101:19000/--/ProductScreen?id=${data.id}`
            });
            if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
                if (result.activityType) {
                    // shared with activity type of result.activityType
                    //console.log('1')
                } else {
                    // shared
                    //console.log('2')
                }
            } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
                // dismissed
            }
        } catch (error) {
            //console.log(error.message)
        }
    }
```

This is how i share my product, and i can handle that on local it is working fine. But i should make it work on development as well.